# Android TAKE_PHOTO_WITH_DATA cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, media

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent,TAKE_PHOTO_WITH_DATA);
```

Hi all,I got two questions.
the code above show an "TAKE_PHOTO_WITH_DATA cannot be resolved to a variable" error,
I use sdk 2.2.3 but change to 4.2.2 the error still there,
what's wrong with "TAKE_PHOTO_WITH_DATA"?
by the way,
Is there any "TAKE_VIDEO_WITH_DATA" or "TAKE_SOUND_WITH_DATA"  can use? 
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It will show an error as long as you don't declare the particular variable,`TAKE_PHOTO_WITH_DATA` is nothing but a request code,you can even use an integer directly instead of this like `startActivityForResult(intent,1);` it is just for checking the results you can read more about **request codes** in the [android developer site](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)